# IIS-Error: Could not load type 'IsapiModule'

Tags: asp.net, iis, umbraco, iis-8

I have a new windows server. On this server I want to run an umbraco website.

I had to add the Handler Mappings for aspx files manually. Now I get this error:

> "Could not load type 'IsapiModule'".

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick search:

> In windows go to  `Programs and features -> Turn windows features
>   on/off`
>
> Then in the tree structure find
>
> 'Internet Informatiuon Service'
>
> - 'World wide Web Services'
>
> -- 'application development features'
>
> and make sure the 'ISAPI Extension' and 'ISAPI filter' is checked
>   (depending on what u want)

### Update:

You have them installed -- good. Next time please give as much details as possible about your issue (current configuration, what have you tried, etc.).

Do you have the Asp.Net SDK installed? Which version of Asp.Net are you using? Is your pool well configured?

Comment: they are both installed

Comment: @B5-NDDT do you have the SDK installed? Which version of Asp.Net is it?

Comment: I found a workarround with plesk. Thanks for your help